# Animate classes as they come into view

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, scrollview, jquery-waypoints

I'm trying to fadeIn my div blocks one-at-a-time as the block scrolls into view, they would then fadeOut when almost out of view.

So far I have achieved this using JQuery Waypoints, However all the blocks fadeIn and out at once, this is because I'm targeting the class.

See my code:

```
// scrolling down
$portfolioRow.waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction === 'down') {
        $($portfolioRow).find(".portfolio-block-text").removeClass('no-opacity');
    }
}, { offset: '50%' });

// scrolling up
$portfolioRow.waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction === 'up') {
        $($portfolioRow).find(".portfolio-block-text").addClass('no-opacity');
    }
}, { offset: '90%' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Waypoints handler you should be able to access the individual waypoint element using `this.element`.

Try changing:

```
$($portfolioRow).find( etc.
```

to:

```
$(this.element).find( etc.
```

Here is a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/me7ye126/

My fiddle uses vanilla JS Waypoints syntax (I couldn't get Waypoints jQuery syntax to work in JSFiddle for some reason), but `$(this.element)` should work either way.